# MVC3 application: What folder to use for saving files on the server?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I have an application MVC3 application.  I want to log various things, like when a form particular form is submitted, to avoid having to write to a database, I want to log the details in an xml file.

The question is what folder should I use, some of the examples I have seen suggest the App_Data folder.  What is the norm or recommended for the least issues?

So I use this:

```
// Create a new XmlSerializer instance with the type of the test class
var serializerObj = new XmlSerializer(typeof(CourseApplicationVM));
// Create a new file stream to write the serialized object to a file

var filename = string.Format("{0}-{1}-{2}{3}", "CourseApp",
                                viewModel.Course.Code + viewModel.Applicant.Name, DateTime.Now.Ticks, ".xml");
var filepath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Log"), filename);

TextWriter writeFileStream = new StreamWriter(filepath);
serializerObj.Serialize(writeFileStream, viewModel);
// Cleanup
writeFileStream.Close();
```

It works fine locally, but not when published to the server.  Upon looking at the folder structure it is unsurprising, as it doesn't even have the App_Data folder when published.  Which leads to this error:

```
Could not find a part of the path 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\MyApplication\App_Data\Log\CourseApp-0385JoeBloggs-634734549879496695.xml'. 

Exception Details: System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\MyApplication\App_Data\Log\CourseApp-0385JoeBloggs-634734549879496695.xml'.
```

Why is it that is hasn't got that folder (shouldn't it be published up)?  And what is the normal location for the saving of such things?

Thanks,
David

Comment: Have you added into your solution

Comment: I have added the log folder within App_Data and included that yes.

Comment: So I have to deliberately add an unrequired file to the folder before it will publish its structure?
It has now created it with adding a fake file.  Madness.

Answer (score 1):

Right Click on the folder and in context menu select "Include in to project/solution"

Make sure you rights on folder are set accordingly.

Comment: As I've said, that doesn't work unless I place an arbitrary file in said folder. :(

Comment: sorry for my last comment... you have to right click on the folder. not  a file?